# Digitar e pesquisar na ComboBox

Tags: java, mysql

Gostaria de saber se tem jeito e como fazer: digitar e ir aparecendo os nomes em uma ComboBox, já está listando os dados do banco na combobox, porém gostaria de digitar a inicial do nome e ir listando.
 **O código:**

```
public void listarAssociadosnoComboboxV() throws Exception {
        try {

            Cad_Veiculo.cmbfk_associadoV.addItem("SELECIONE");
            String sql = "SELECT ID_ASSOCIADO, NOME FROM ASSOCIADO";



            preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                  Associado a = new Associado();
                  a.setIdAssociado(rs.getInt("ID_ASSOCIADO") );
                  a.setNome( rs.getString("NOME") );
                  Cad_Veiculo.cmbfk_associadoV.addItem(a) ;        
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        }finally {
            Conexao.closeConnection(conexao, preparedStatement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Poderia acrescentar informação na pergunta de como está a ocorrer a associação dos dados com a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

- Pensando que a sua base de dados poderá mudar depois da primeira população, a melhor forma de fazer o que deseja é sempre que alguém digita algum caracter na sua combobox será feito um pedido ao servidor e pesquisará com um like 'caracter%' a sua tabela na base de dados e popula de novo a combobox.

**Query que precisa de usar:**

> SELECT ID_ASSOCIADO, NOME FROM ASSOCIADO WHERE NOME LIKE 'caracter%'

- Outra forma é ter em Javascript uma lista de objetos e sobre estes filtrar consoante os caracteres digitados na combobox.

Agora escolha a opção que mais se adequa ao que pretende.